# Drools, how to check if an object with a specific property exists more than once in the list

Tags: drools

I have a number of PersonEntitys in my working memory. I need to write a rule to check if two PersonEntitys with the same someProperty are existed in the working memory. I have written as follows, but the problem is, when  there are really two PersonEntitys with same someProperty, the sys.out is executing twice:

```
when 
    $person : PersonEntity(person.personType == PersonType.LegalPerson);
    $personList : ArrayList( size > 1 ) from collect( PersonEntity(someProperty.id == $legalPerson.someProperty.id))    

then
    System.out.println("error occured");
```

I also tried this, but I think since my working memory has a number of PersonEntities, the rule is executing 4times (number of PersonEntitys) and my "error occurred " sentence appears 4times in console:

```
  PersonEntity(some conditions, $relatedId :relatedPerson.id); 
  exists PersonEntity(some conditions, relatedPerson.id > $relatedId)
```

Comment: The last pair of conditions is omitting the `not` pattern (2nd and 3rd rule in my answer). Omitting this binds each PersonEntity to your first pattern (and $person), and therefore the rule fires once for each PersonEntity. Only if you restrict this to the smallest id you'll get only one activation.

Comment: Also, is this "relatedPerson" a single unique entity associated with each PErsonEntity? Note that what you need for the ordering must be a unique (numeric) key value.

Comment: unfortunately no, my personEntities dont have a unique id in this step (it is not persisted yet...) relatedPerson is an association of PersonEntity. and i want to know if there is tow entities with the same relatedPerson in working memory

Comment: Persisting has nothing to do with having a unique numeric property. You can add this on object creation, use a static counter. And: why do you use > when you are looking for same related person? Originally, it was personType - it's difficult to advice if you don't follow the proposals and keep changing the goal all the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard solution to this problem is to add another constraint using a unique property which guarantees an ordering.

```
when
   PersonEntity(personType == PersonType.LegalPerson, $pid: personId)
   exists PersonEntity(personType == PersonType.LegalPerson, personId > $pid)
then
   // two LegalPerson
```

If you expect three or more of the same, you may even have to add another pattern to block multiple activations:

```
when
   PersonEntity(personType == PersonType.LegalPerson, $pid: personId)
   not PersonEntity(personType == PersonType.LegalPerson, personId < $pid )
   exists PersonEntity(personType == PersonType.LegalPerson, personId > $pid)
then
   // two or more LegalPerson
```

(The suggestion to use collect isn't good unless you really need all of these.)

This will work even when you need to check for any personType:

```
 when
   PersonEntity( $pt: personType, $pid: personId)
   not PersonEntity(personType == $pt, personId < $pid )
   exists PersonEntity(personType == $pt, personId > $pid)
then
   // two or more $pt
```

Here you may add a collect instead of the third pattern to get all such PersonEntity facts.

Comment: what is personId in your sample? my PersonEntitys haven't persisted yet and therefore has no id...

Comment: i used your suggestion as follows, but I think since my working memory has a number of PersonEntities (instead of a list of PersonEntitys), the rule is executing more than once (number of PersonEntitys) and my "error occurred " sentence appears more than once in console:                   PersonEntity(some conditions, $relatedId :relatedPerson.id);
    exists PersonEntity(some conditions, relatedPerson.id == $relatedId)

Comment: Did you use the `$id: id* and `id > $id` constraints?

Comment: yes but it didnt make any changes, i dont know how to say that execute the rule only once

Comment: So what exactly did you used? Add it to your question, or else it won't be readable.